# How to use fetch to query nested parameters for GET in a REST API?

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch

I'm looking at the docs for an API, and here's what it looks like:

```
List Contacts
Retrieves a list of contacts

QUERY PARAMETERS
filter      string
            Filter to apply, allowed fields are:

            (String) email
            (String) given_name
            (String) family_name
            (String) company_id
            (Set[String]) contact_ids
            (String) start_update_time
            (String) end_update_time

order_by    string
            Attribute and direction to order items.
            One of the following fields:

            id
            date_created
            email
            One of the following directions:
            asc
            desc

page_size   integer <int32> [ 1 .. 1000 ]
            Total number of items to return per page
```

I'm able to get page size using this:

```js
fetch("https://api/crm/rest/v2/contacts?page_size=10").then(async res => {
    console.log(await res.json())
)
```

But what would be the standard way of querying the nested fields of `filter` or `orderby`?

EDIT: I'm assuming this is a limitation of my knowledge rather than poor documentation. There's no other information or examples.

Comment: Which nested fields?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a limitation of your knowledge, it *is* poor documentation if that's all you got.

There is no single accepted standard for encoding these. They might be comma-separated, or they might use PHP-style brackets `[]`, which is also supported in for example Node's 'extended' querystring parser.

The documentation *should* specify.